# Mad scientist that changes men into gill men

Tags: movie, story-identification

It was probably a Creature Feature movie.  It was definitely black and white.  It was definitely on a boat - not a submarine.  And I also remember that the mad scientist changed the man into the gill man in stages.  He first changed the skin.  And I remember well the last stage was that he did surgery and cut the man's back or chest open and he inserted and oxygen tank.  It seems funny but that is what he did.  I remember it and I would like to find this movie again too if anybody could remember the title of the film.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identify horror film/TV show where protagonists ostensibly hunting a Gill-Man are transformed into same](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84033/identify-horror-film-tv-show-where-protagonists-ostensibly-hunting-a-gill-man-ar)

Comment: You did the right thing, splitting this into its own question.

Comment: yes, Paulie_D.  I think you are right.  I just wish somebody could remember the name of the movie.

Comment: @Paulie_D we don't close story ID requests as duplicate except when both questions share a (formally or informally) accepted answer.

Comment: No but the OP specifically stated (pre-revision) that this was a duplicate.

Comment: Is the OP certain that this is a duplicate? I got the impression from the OP's comment that the OP still had some doubt about that. We don't close when duplicates are merely likely, even when the likelihood is strong.

Comment: [Our agreed policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance?noredirect=1&lq=1) is that we don't close duplicates **unless both questions have an identical answer that has been confirmed by both OPs.**